# Figure with uneven size images

Tags: includegraphics

I would like to create a figure with five images as shown in the attached file (2 images on the left, and 3 on the right side) and put a thin black border around all five images. I only know how to put images side to side
like this:

```
 \begin{figure}[!h]
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image1.eps}
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image3.eps}
 \end{figure}
```

[image: example]

But this does not help me in this case. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\vspace*{1.5cm}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\vspace*{0.5cm}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
\vspace*{0.5cm}

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

@JohnKormylo had the good idea to use minipages of a specific height:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{minipage}[c][8cm][c]{.45\textwidth}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\vfill

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c][8cm][c]{.45\textwidth}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}
\vfill

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
\vfill

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works exactly the way I wanted!

Comment: You could also specify the height of the minipages (optional) and use \vfill to fill in the gaps.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Good idea!